# All commands error when running in my for /f loop "not recognised as an internal or external command"

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a bizarre issue which I hope someone can help me with. I have a batch script that uses a `FOR /F` loop to read from a file and set variables accordingly. The command is written as follows:

```
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1-3 delims=," %%A in ('type "C:\ReconfigureSettingsFile.csv"') do (commands)
```

The error is:

> 'type "C:\ReconfigureSettingsFile.csv"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

It happens even if I run this:

```
for /f "usebackq delims==" %i in (`set`) do @echo %i
```

> 'set' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: You don't need `type`. Just use `in ("C:\ReconfigureSettingsFile.csv")` instead.

Comment: Doesn't seem to matter whether I use type or not. I get the same result

Comment: There's a vast difference between the two, so there's no way running with or without `type` would produce the same output.

Comment: The key here is that no matter what the command in the brackets it results in the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems:

1. If you use `/f`, you tell the for-loop to read a file. Don't mix that with commands.
2. If you use backticks (`), you tell the for-loop to execute a command. You have used straight ticks (')
3. If you want to use quotation marks for the file name, use `usebackq`

So either use

```
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1-3 delims=," %%A in (C:\ReconfigureSettingsFile.csv) do (commands)
```

without `type` and without quotes or

```
FOR /F "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1-3 delims=," %%A in ("C:\ReconfigureSettingsFile.csv") do (commands)
```

without `type` but with quotes or

```
FOR "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1-3 delims=," %%A in (`type "C:\ReconfigureSettingsFile.csv"`) do (commands)
```

with `type` but without `/F`.

Don't forget to use `%%A`, `%%B` and `%%C` in the commands.

Comment: Hi Thomas - Thank you. The second command worked - I don't know why I originally used the TYPE inside the brackets. Anyway I have it working now.
Heres the odd thing though, my old command worked fine on most servers without issue, it was just two new servers that I had this issue.
Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 2):

If the value of the `%COMSPEC%` environment variable is wrong, `FOR /F` with a command will report the "not recognized as an internal or external command" error.

In the registry, `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\ComSpec` should have a type of `REG_EXPAND_SZ` and be set to `%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe` (at least on Windows 7).

Comment: `For /F` still works if you nul the `comspec` variable in the cmd prompt, but you are correct if it is set to something invalid then the error occurs.